# undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError)?

Tags: ruby

```
   3.2.0 :002 > File.exists?("xyz")
(irb):2:in `<main>': undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exist?                             
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: don't forget to "accept" his answer.  It increases the chances that people will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the question mark (`?`) at the end:

```
File.exist? 'foo'
File.exists? 'foo'
```

In general, methods which answer questions will always end with a question mark.

In this case, the method is asking `File` the `does 'foo' exist?` question. The class will return the answer.

Comment: Hah!  I thought that was some kind of annotation in the documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: @Klortho, methods can have `!` and `=` at the end of their names as well.

Comment: One more note, there is no authoritative mandate to use ?/!/=, it is simply a helpful conventional.

Comment: I consider the ending `?` a reminder that the method returns a boolean true/false. It implies that there is a question being asked because of punctuation in English, but the method should return a boolean.

Answer (score 52):

Starting in **Ruby 3.2.0** the `exists?` (pluralized) alias for `exist?` seems to has been removed.

With **Ruby 3.2.0**, be sure to use the singular-form `exist?`

```
% rvm use 3.1.3
Using /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3
jason@MBA22.local /Users/jason/Work/Hot_Glue/Example Apps/AltLookup1 [main]
% irb  
3.1.3 :001 > File.exist?("xyz")
 => false 
3.1.3 :002 > File.exists?("xyz")
 => false 
3.1.3 :003 > exit
jason@MBA22.local /Users/jason/Work/Hot_Glue/Example Apps/AltLookup1 [main]
% rvm use 3.2.0
Using /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0
jason@MBA22.local /Users/jason/Work/Hot_Glue/Example Apps/AltLookup1 [main]
% irb
3.2.0 :001 > File.exist?("xyz")
 => false 
3.2.0 :002 > File.exists?("xyz")
(irb):2:in `<main>': undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exist?                             
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did Ruby authors break other innocent and standard things?

Comment: `File.exists?` was deprecated back in Ruby 2.1, but remained in the language for several years until now. You can find all of the removed features in the release notes,  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/12/25/ruby-3-2-0-released/ scroll down to "Removed constants" and "Removed methdos"

Comment: Wow, that was an utterly baffling decision by the developers. I get that they want to unify function names but they could've just left it in as an deprecated alias for backwards compatibility. Something like this in no way warrants such a breaking change.

Comment: To clarify, in the natural English language "exists" is NOT a "pluralized" form, but a "third person singular". Likewise "exist" is not a "singular-form".

It looks strange to me that "exist" was chosen over "exists" – after all we are asking about a single File. However, I am neither native English speaker nor (primarily) a Ruby developer :-D

Comment: It's because Matz is Japanese, and Ruby's pluralization idioms are from a Japanese sensibility. My sense is that what happened is that after years of getting criticism around incorrect pluralization, Matz decided to go with singular-case across the entire language, which seems like the direction Ruby is moving in. If I were Japanese speaker I could see how this makes sense but I agree for English speakers it sounds very unnatural.